# Apache Spark - Memory management

Tags: memory, apache-spark, ram

So assume i've got a cluster with 100 GB memory for spark to utilize. I got a dataset of 2000 GB  and want to run a iterative application o  this dataset. 200 iterations.

My question is, when using .cache(), will spark keep the first 100 GB in memory and perform the 200 iteration before reading the next 100 GB automatically?

When working within the memory limit sparks advantages are very clear, but when working with larger datasets im not entirely sure how spark and yarn manages the data.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the behaviour you will see. Spark's caching is done using LRU eviction, so if you cache a dataset which is too big for memory, only the most recently used part will be kept in memory. However, spark also has a MEMORY_AND_DISK persistence mode (described in more detail at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence ) which sounds like it could be a good fit for your case.

Comment: Thanks. So when using .persist() with  MEMORY_AND_DISK  argument, spark will have to read from disk after each iteration? The gain would be that the RDD wont be recomputed using the lineage after each iteration, right?

Comment: That is the idea. Generally reading from local disk is faster than recomputing the data.